# Oracle PL/SQL dynamically create name for Procedure and Policy

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic, plsql, policy

I'm trying to see if the following would be possible.

it all hinges on creating Policies and Procedures for each row..
Is it possible to create a dynamically named Procedure and pass that name to a dynamically
named policy?

So as following create these in a loop ??

I have an email alert

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE caps_email_alert (sch varchar2, tab varchar2, pol  varchar2)
AS
    msg varchar2(20000) := 'CAPS.ME_PAYEE table violation. The time is: ';
BEGIN
    msg := msg||to_char(SYSDATE, 'Day DD MON, YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

    UTL_MAIL.SEND (
    sender => 'me@somewhere.com',
    recipients => 'me@somewhere.com',
    subject => 'Table modification on caps.me_payee',
    message => msg);
END caps_email_alert;
/
```

and a policy that will call it...

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_FGA.ADD_POLICY (
  object_schema      =>  'CAPS',
  object_name        =>  'ME_PAYEE',
  policy_name        =>  'CHK_CAPS_ME_PAYEE',
  audit_column       =>  'CARRIER_NO',
  audit_condition    =>  'CARRIER_NO = ''20'' ',   
  handler_schema     =>  'SYSADMIN_FGA',
  handler_module     =>  'CAPS_EMAIL_ALERT',
  enable             =>   TRUE,
  statement_types    =>  'SELECT, UPDATE',
  audit_trail        =>   DBMS_FGA.DB + DBMS_FGA.EXTENDED); 
END;
/
```

I would need to write a subprogram that would execute as follows...
( to create a Procedure and Policy for each row )

```
BEGIN
   FOR c IN (SELECT schema as sch, table as tab, cond as pred FROM slac_red_table) LOOP

      --here need to create dynamically named procedure and pass it to a dynamically named policy
      --so a function that creates a dynamically named procedure
      emailerProcedureName emailerProcedureName%TYPE := emailerFunction(c.sch, c.tab)
      createPolicyFunction(c.sch, c.tab, c.cond,emailerProcedureName)

   END LOOP;
END;
```

Maybe I can accomplish the same some other way... have you encountered something similar ?